# How to get the value only in lua?

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching

I want to only get the value. How to get the value only?
Is there any pattern matching? I especially trouble in '='

```
DeviceName=
ManufacturerId=ABC76
SerialNo=100
ModelId=BDF2015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Lua's pattern matching for this task:

```
s=[[
DeviceName=
ManufacturerId=ABC76
SerialNo=100
ModelId=BDF2015
]]

for k,v in s:gmatch("(%S+)=(%S*)") do
    print(k,'['..v..']')
end
```

Output

```
DeviceName  []
ManufacturerId  [ABC76]
SerialNo    [100]
ModelId [BDF2015]
```

Comment: This is much better. Thanks!

Comment: Usually in INI-files equality sign `"="` and space `" "` are allowed inside the values, so `"(%S+)=(%S*)"` should be replaced with `"(%S.-)=(.-)%f[\r\n%z]"`

Answer (score 0):

the regex for that would be:

```
\SerialNo=(.*)
```

Comment: Is there any regex that extract only one value? (ex. Just extract only serial number value)

Comment: I edited the answer. You can simply replace `SerialNo=` either using regex or in any language easily. My solution is simple and it will not confuse you. Plus, it is not playing with the spaces etc. It works for whatever example you provided

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18093887)

Comment: @rajeshujade have you read the question yourself? this answers the question. You can use the asker's example, and the regex in my answer and regex tester website you test it yourself, please review with care!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(\t| )*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*(\t| )*=(\t| )*(.*)$
```

and a backreference to `$4` or `\4`

it will work perfectly for the following assignation (with spaces)

```
DeviceName  =
ManufacturerId=  ABC76
SerialNo = 100
ModelId=BDF2015
```

**However, beware that the multiple assignations on the same line will not work with this regex!!!!**

You will also have to adapt it for **local** declaration.

The following assignations will not be extracted properly!

```
local d , f = 5 ,10 
d , f = 5, 10;      
d, f = 10
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try

Comment: where you able to get what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for only one value like BDF2015. I've tried in regex tester

Comment: Great! Good luck :-)

Comment: @Allan This does not work for the example the asker has provided, you cannot manipulate the example to make it fit your answer